# Is there a way to safely downgrade from MariaDB to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7, downgrade

I am running cPanel/WHM with MariaDB, it seems that at least according to their sayings is not possible with their built in system to downgrade this automaticly. What about other ways to do it? Does someone have experience with such downgrades, if so please advice. Running Centos 7.

Comment: why do you want to do this ?

Comment: Because of the issues in past with MYSQL Governor, and due to low compatibility with MYSQL Workbench. Plus everyone recommended me to do so.

Comment: so , MariaDB is the better faster and has more features as MySQL. Its more flexible. So not MariaDB is the issue, Workbench is the issue. I will never downgrade to MySQL. MariaDB Wins 2015 Members’ Choice Database of the Year.  https://mariadb.com/blog/mariadb-wins-2015-members-choice-database-year-linuxquestionsorg-thank-you#

Comment: What about MongoDB, I heard is much better?

Comment: Can you point me to some mariadb real optimisation stuff, I have a website that loads heavy as hell.

Comment: Switching to MongoDB requires major rewrite of _your application code_.  Why even consider it?

Comment: @RickJames I find that useful hint, I will not change to MongoDB, yet a downgrade would be usefull to return back to MySQL, or as said MariaDB is good choise. Maybe I will stick with it.

Comment: "Heavy loads" usually implies less-than-optimal indexes and queries.  Let's see some of the heavy queries, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: @RickJames any concrete commands I should run? Should I make a table with the above statements?

Comment: Set `long_query_time=1`, turn on the slowlog, wait a day, then use `mysqldumpslow -s t` or `pt-query-digest` to summarize the slowlog.  Then do the `SHOW` and `EXPLAIN` of the "worst" queries in the summary.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks a lot, I will do so.

Comment: Here is a show create table: https://gist.github.com/highacid/d9ad3448287aa3beb074 I could not find a way to run SHOW SELECT yet, still checking. And here is my slow query log, it was enabled by some time now. https://gist.github.com/highacid/74b8f1825e08d797e65d